# how to use phpunit and xdebug to get code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

I want to get code coverage for a web site.
I need to do manual test instead of writing code.

The source code of the web site and xdebug, phpunit are on a linux server.now I start apache and open the web site.
I just don't know how to get the coverage of my manual test.

what I expect is this:

1. Make some config on server
2. Open my web site and do many manual test
3. Use some method to get the code coverage

Dose phpunit + xdebug can do this?
I need a report, html is good.

PS. I am a newer... my English and skill is not very well... so Please be patient, Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

Simply follow all steps in the [PHPUnit Manual, Code-Coverage Analysis](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/code-coverage-analysis.html).

If you want to do code coverage with manual fronted tests. Hava a look at [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) together with [PHP Unit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html).

Comment: the manual is not for test web site. And ... I am not familiar with php... so.. is there some case for my requirement?

Comment: as I know ,selenium is for automation test, but my test is totally manual.. all I want is that I go to the site and use some function, and get the code coverage of what code I  have used, what code not use.

Comment: Since Selenium is a fronted test tool. The manual shows you how to get code coverage reports from fronted tests. However they are created, manually or automated. This is not easy! Difficulty level: extreme! I'm using Xdebug, and Selenium and PHPUnit for more than 5 years but this task is **not** simple!

Comment: Is that mean ... It's very difficult to get code coverage of manual test on my site?  whatever using phpunit.. xdebug.. or selenium?

Comment: Yes it is difficult. Use PHPUnit together with Xdebug. And do your tests manually.